# Number validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have created an external JavaScript to validate a form I created in HTML. Some of the validation works, but when I use the same code to validate other fields it will not work. E.g. postcode must contain numbers - if not, postcode is invalid.

I tried using the same code for a credit card, i.e. credit card must have 16 digits - if not, the credit card number is invalid. I wrote the code for postcode and it worked, but when I tried to reaarrange it to suit the credit card function, it did not work. Not too sure why? Should I have used a different function?

Here is my external javascript:

```
function validateForm()
{   
     if (isNaN(document.getElementById("postcode").value))
     {
         alert ("Your postcode is not valid");
     }
     else 
     {
         alert ("You have entered your postcode correctly");
     }

    if (document.getElementById ("email").value.length < 5 ||     
        document.getElementById ("email").value.indexOf("@")== -1) 
    {
        alert("Please enter your email min 5 chars and include @ symbol");
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(document.getElementById("creditcard").value))
    {
        alert ("Your creditcard is not valid");
    }
    else 
    {
    alert ("You have entered your creditcard correctly");
    }

    alert("Thank you for your submission!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: not all credit cards have 16 digits...   be very cautious about making up your own validation rules based on invalid assumptions...

Comment: What didn't work? Did the form still submit? If so it's because you didn't add a return false.

Comment: Yes I know but I just chose 16 just to test my form. The form submits and say if I input invalid data into the postcode field a alert message will pop but if I do the same with the credit card field nothing will pop up. No alert message like it should.

Comment: you will need to check following - 1. You must have an element with **id** - **postcode**
2. Add a debugger to your function to check/identify where it is failing
3. Use the browsers developer console and check for any error(if you are using chrome the use F12

Also please use return false when the input is wrong,as @adeneo suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off, you probably don't want to prompt the user with 10 error dialogs at a time. 
So you should nest your `if else` clauses & the function will stop after the first error.
Second, `isNaN` is doubtfully a good evaluator because `input.value` may return a value of type string. Using a regex is a more robust way of error checking inputs. Third, you want to account for the user's confusion mistakes. Users often think (me too): 'wait, should I also write the dash on my credit card here?'.

So you'll remove dots, dashes & whitespace before proceeding (those could unknowingly be included). Other chars are just invalid. For your credit card input, that would be:

```
var ccVal = document.getElementById("creditcard").value;

// remove dots, dashes & whitespace
ccVal = ccVal.replace(/(\s|\.|\-)/g, ''); 

// if any other chars there, input value = incorrect & stop function
if ( ccVal.match(/\D/) ) { 
  alert('A credit card number only has decimals, silly.');
  return false;
} else {
  // Check for length now
  if ( ccVal.length !== 16) {
    alert('A credit card has 16 decimals, silly.');
    return false;
  } else {
    // more checks
    document.getElementById('myform').submit()
  }
}
```

See an implementation example here: http://jsbin.com/betawahi/1/edit

Comment: Still didnt work. Maybe I entering it wrong. Would you be able to test it on your end if I send you the files?

Comment: @user3699543, no that won't be necessary. I have added an example to the post where you can see it works. :) I had to tweak the code a little bit, (match instead of indexOf, dunno why it didn't work). Also, this works only if your submit button has a `type="button"` and you submit the form only through JS with `.submit()`. The `return` statements don't block the submit otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN checks if the value is not an integer, you'll need an additional check for the length.

Keeping the code similar to the way you've set out the rest of the function, to check if the credit card is a number and a length of 16, you'll want:

```
if( !(isNaN(document.getElementById("creditcard").value) && document.getElementById("creditcard").value.length === 16) {
    alert("Credit Card Is Valid");
}else{
    alert("Your Credit Card is Not Valid");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still the samething. Only postcode will pop up with a alert message not for the credit card.